# Virtual Directory IIS and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, virtual-directory

This is probably something that is a quick fix, but I cannot seem to locate an answer. I added a virtual directory to my site (MVC 4) and have it set to run as its own application. However, the image files are all trying to be accessed from the root of the site, not the virtual directory. I've changed the paths in the CSS files but that didn't seem to solve the problem. Do I really have to hard code the absolute paths to all my files vs. `@Url.Content("~")`?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you created virtual directory inside an application?

Comment: No, it's a virtual directory inside a web site. Basically, the main site is a web development company site and the directory is a single client's development so they can view progress.

Answer (score 1):

**Referencing images from CSS**

Make the paths in the stylesheet relative to the location of the stylesheet.

So, if your stylesheet is in `Content\Site.css` and you want to reference an image in `Images`, use the path `'../Images/<filename>'` in `Site.css`. That way, the path will be correct no matter what virtual directory your app is served from.

In other words, to use `myimage.png` as a background image, you would put something like this in `Site.css`:

```
#mydiv { background-image: url('../Images/myimage.png'); }
```

**Referencing images from Razor view**

When referencing a static image from a razor view, use the `@Url.Content("~/pathtofile")` method, or, better yet, use [T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/documentation) (see section 2.4 on that page).

Hope this helps.

Comment: To clarify, my url references should be pointing to the content within the virtual directory, but it keeps looking for them in the main site. Is it possible that the _Layout file reference to the css files is incorrect like this?  @Url.Content("~/style.css")

Answer (score 0):

Hardcoding is a bad idea. Use @Url.Content() instead.

Comment: I am using helpers within razor syntax already, but not within the css files. The path keeps wanting to refer to the main site, but not the virtual directory.

Comment: Weird, I'm in the same situation you are (MVC4 app as a virtual app inside another site) and I don't have that problem.
Are you using bundles? It would be useful if you include a little portion of your .css that refers to external content as well as how you are including that .css on your view.

Comment: Hi, I'm not using bundles. In my Layout, I have the following references to css:

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/css/style.css")"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/css/media.css")"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/css/revolution.css")" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/css/media-slideshow.css")" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/css/noscript.css")" media="screen,all" id="noscript"/>

Comment: In the view, they are referenced within the stylesheets themselves via classes and all are pointed to as, for example, "../images". I've tried "/images" as well...

Comment: It seems that your images are at the same level of your css folder, is that correct?
I have my .css in /Content and my images in /Content/images and my classes are defined like:
url(images/yourimage.png)

Comment: Do you see any difference when you add a / at the end of your subdomain URL?
"http://www.yoursite.com/app" vs "http://www.yoursite.com/app/" ?